# Angular Typescript - Async await on internal subscription

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a function like this;

```
openModalWhenRemoveItem() {
  callRemoveService();
  openMyModal();
}
```

`callRemoveService()` function has a subscribe and it's async function, the `openMyModal()` function must be invoked after `callRemoteService()`

```
callRemoveService() {
  combineLatest(myAccountSelector$, myCompanySelector$).pipe(
    switchMap(res) => 
    this.myService.remove(res[0].id, res[1].id))
    .subscribe((res)=> console.log(res))
}
```

I need to create a function that has to wait the internal subscription in `callRemoveService()` before calling the `openModal()`. I want to try with `async await` but I can't find a solution. I tried in this way:

```
async callRemoveService() {
  await combineLatest(myAccountSelector$, myCompanySelector$).pipe(
    switchMap(res) => 
    this.myService.remove(res[0].id, res[1].id))
    .subscribe((res)=> console.log(res))
}

openModalWhenRemoveItem() {
  callRemoveService().then(() => {openMyModal();});
  
}
```

but it doesn't work. I cant put `openMyModal()` function into subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in your case would be to return the `Observable` from the `callRemoveService` method instead of subscribing to it. The caveat with this approach is that you need to call `subscribe` in all the places where you call `callRemoveService`.

If you do that, then it is trivial:

```
callRemoveService(): Observable<any> {
  return combineLatest(myAccountSelector$, myCompanySelector$).pipe(
    switchMap(res) => 
    this.myService.remove(res[0].id, res[1].id));
}
```

Then your `openModalWhenRemoveItem` method becomes this:

```
openModalWhenRemoveItem() {
  callRemoveService().subscribe(() => {
    openMyModal();
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`combineLatest` is a RxJS operator, it returns an Observable. You can't simply await an Observable, it's not a Promise. Simply subscribe to it.

```
callRemoveService(): Observable<any> {
  return combineLatest(myAccountSelector$, myCompanySelector$);
}
```

and then :

```
openModalWhenRemoveItem() {
  callRemoveService().subscribe(openMyModal);
}
```

Alternatively, you can transform your Observable to Promise using the `lastValueFrom` operator, and await it :

```
callRemoveService(): Promise<any> {
  return lastValueFrom( combineLatest(myAccountSelector$, myCompanySelector$)) ;
}

async openModalWhenRemoveItem() {
  await callRemoveService();
  openMyModal();
}
```